# I am trying to add up all the numbers in a file which contains numbers separated by space and are contained in multiple lines using MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My output is coming wrong. The Input File is:

1 2 3 4
5 4 3 2

Output should be key: sum      value:    24

Output produced by MapReduce: key: sum    value: 34

I am using OpenJDK 7 in Ubuntu 14.04 to run the jar file whereas, the jar file was created in Eclipse Juna and the java version used was Oracle JDK 7 to compile it.
NumberDriver.java

package numbersum;

```
import java.io.*;
//import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
public class NumberDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Configuration conf=new Configuration();
            String[] otherArgs=new GenericOptionsParser(conf,args).getRemainingArgs();
            if(otherArgs.length!=2)
            {
                System.err.println("Error");
                System.exit(2);
            }
            Job job=new Job(conf, "number sum");
            job.setJarByClass(NumberDriver.class);
            job.setMapperClass(NumberMapper.class);
            job.setReducerClass(NumberReducer.class);
            job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
            System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }

}
```

NumberMapper.java

```
package numbersum;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

//import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
//import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
//import org.hsqldb.Tokenizer;

public class NumberMapper extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 
    {
        int sum;
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            StringTokenizer itr=new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while(itr.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                sum+=Integer.parseInt(itr.nextToken());
            }
            context.write(new Text("sum"),new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }
```

NumberReducer.java

```
package numbersum;
import java.io.*;
//import java.util.StringTokenizer;

//import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
//import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
//import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

public class NumberReducer extends Reducer <Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key,Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int sum=0;
            for(IntWritable value:values)
                {
                    sum+=value.get();
                }
            context.write(key,new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My best guess:

```
    int sum; // <-- Why a class member?
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        int sum = 0; //Why not here?
        StringTokenizer itr=new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
```

---

Reasoning for the guess:
1st map: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10
2nd map:(10 +) 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 34

..meaning, the previous value is being retained.

Comment: thanks a lot ... it worked. Declaring it as a class member doesn't flush its value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to set `sum` to `0` at the begining of `map` function:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    sum = 0;
...
```

Comment: No instance variables get zero value by default.